# Refactor on save in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: refactoring, visual-studio-2019

I love Prettier for VS Code. I want to do similar things in Visual Studio (2019).

It now has 'Wrap, indent, and align parameters or arguments' for example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/wrap-align-indent-parameters?view=vs-2019); and I'd like to do this automatically whenever I save the file.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Or if there's a free extension that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a free plugin but you can get quite a long way towards this with some muscle memory and the built in autoformat command.
 <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> 
will do code indentation and formatting, and save the file. 
If you have Resharper (sorry), there's a configurable code cleanup tool which will do what you want and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> will do the cleanup and save.

Comment: But I don't know how to tell VS2019 which formatting style I prefer? If I have a long line with arguments and I use Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D - its equally valid to "Wrap all arguments" or "Unwrap every argument" or "Wrap long argument list". I need an equivalent of a .prettierrc file to tell VS2019 which settings I prefer, right?

Comment: Sadly, that's what resharper will get you

Answer (score 2):

Mads Kristensen (a Microsoft employee who makes scads of Visual Studio extensions [and teaches you to too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MvJnod5Xb5g)!) made a JsPrettier extension for "classic" Visual Studio (ie, *not* VS Code):

https://github.com/madskristensen/JavaScriptPrettier

It **does** <strike>not</strike> format on save if you set that up in its settings.

[image: jsprettier extension context menu]

If it's literally Prettier in Visual Studio that you're after, this isn't a bad option.

Comment: That is a good shout! I generally work in VSCode as much as I can these days - if prettier had a C# formatter, then I would be all over this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [Format document on Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mynkow.FormatdocumentonSave) VS extension does exactly what you want, with one exception. It automatically runs Visual Studio's code cleanup command on save.

Visual Studio's code cleanup commands covers many code style preferences and can be configured with a .editorconfig file. Unfortunately one thing that is not supported by VS yet (not counting Resharper) is line wrap preferences. There is an open ticket for this: [dotnet/roslyn#33872](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/33872)

If and when Roslyn supports line wrap preferences (presumably as a new .editorconfig preference), then Visual Studio code cleanup will enforce it and the extension will apply it on save.

Comment: So nothing which does what Prettier does, yet.